# How to add another directory list into ZAP for force browsing

Tags: security, zap

I'm using ZAP for pen testing. I would like to add another directory list directory-list-2.3-big.txt into ZAP to solve the Premium Wall Challenge for Juice Shop. How would I go about doing this?

Btw I have checked the marketplace, it did not show directory-list-2.3-big.txt, only Directorylist V1.0.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `directory-list` lists are available as add-ons for ZAP. Just hit up the marketplace and install them.

[image]

You can get details on available add-ons here: https://www.zaproxy.org/addons/

Of course you can also use any text file with the [Fuzzer](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/fuzzer/) or [Forced Browse](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/forced-browse/) functionality.

Comment: Btw I have checked the marketplace, it did not show directory-list-2.3-big.txt, only Directorylist V1.0.

Comment: Then you probably already have it installed.